# Windows Phone - Disabled Button Background

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, visualstatemanager

here I'm once more with another question about Windows Phone.

I just created some custom buttons and use they as background on my buttons. I also created a grayed button to show as disabled button.

But if I disable using the button1.isEnabled = false, the background disappear

Searching on the net I found a way using a Style tag, but I never used before. I tried but, it's aways returns me a problem, can someone give me a example? My Code:

```XAML
<Button x:Name="btSalvar" Content="Salvar Cor" Margin="68,477,70,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Height="100" Click="btSalvar_Click" ClickMode="Press" IsEnabled="True" Foreground="White">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="/Imagens/Buttons/ButtonGray01.png"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Is there a way to use Style in Windows Phone 8.1 or another way to set a custom background on button with IsDisabled = false?

Comment: You can also create custom button classes, and you can set the disabled view state there.  Check out the styles for different controls here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/flaviencharlon/archive/2012/12/04/default-styles-and-templates-of-xaml-controls-for-windows-store-apps.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Far as I know Style Triggers are a WPF thing not WP8.1/WIN8.1

So you will have to use the **Visual State Manager** for what you want to do.   So go to the UI Designer then go to the **Document Outline** on the left side of VS2013.  Find your button, right click > Edit Template -> Edit a Copy.   This will create a custom style for that specific button.

You want to change the **Disable State** of the button so change that to.....

```XAML
...
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <!-- here is where we need to change -->
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(ImageBrush.ImageSource)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Assets/YOUR_IMAGE.png"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
....
```

---

Now if you set  that new style as the style of the button, you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In french interface

> Document Outline on the left side of VS2013. Find your button, right click > Edit Template -> Edit a Copy

Menu Format / Modifier le modèle / Modifier une copie.
Cela rajoute dans le xaml le